# Tool for transforming OOP code into AOP

Tags: oop, aop, transformation

Is there any open source tool which can transform the OOP code (irrespective of the programming language i.e. .NET, Java or PHP) into AOP?

Comment: AOP applies cross cutting concerns to code.  Presumably you mean a tool that can find common code across the OOP application, and pull it out into an aspect?  I'd expect you to use a clone detector to find the common code, but there are no tools I know of that will extract clones into aspects.

Comment: About "Presumably you mean a tool that can find common code across the OOP application, and pull it out into an aspect" YES, i am searching for one which shows statistical analysis as well after transforming the OOP code into AOP.

Comment: I know of a tool that *could* do this, but it isn't open source.

Comment: Fine. Can you please provide the url from where i can get it along with documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an "AOPizer".  The problem you appear to want to solve has two parts:

- Finding potentially cross-cutting code in an existing application
- Extracting the code into aspects for that language

1) The first task requires essentially a clone detector.  Many clone detectors only
find identical text; these won't be very helpful because your aspects likely
have parameters that have to be take from the code. (If you are going to log
function arguments, the aspect has to be parameterized somehow by those arguments).
So you want a detector that can find parameterized clones.  You also want
those clones to be *extractable* from the code, so whatever it finds needs to
correspond to some well-defined concept in the programming language (expression,
statements, block, ...)  Many token-based clone detectors can find parameterized-by-identifier clones, but don't understand the language structure, and so they won't
be effective for this task.

Our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) finds clones using the abstract syntax of the targeted language
to guide it; this requires precise language parsers; it has such parsers for PHP, Java, VB.net and C#.  The clones its finds always correspond to language structures as defined by the above.  It will find parameters that are single identifiers, or any larger langauge construct (expression, statement, etc.) which consistently varies across the clones. It produces a human-readable report of clone sets and the precise location of all of their instances, as well as the exact parameter values.  It also generates a machine-readable report of the same information, enabling another tool to take advantage of the detection process.    CloneDR has been used to hunt for such cross-cutting techniques in the past: [From goals to aspects: discovering aspects from requirements goal models](http://www-di.inf.puc-rio.br/~julio/yu04re.pdf)  (I'm the author of CloneDR).

2) Armed with clone data, you now need a tool that can extract the clones into aspects. First, you need to define the aspect language, then you need a tool that can parse the langauge, pin point the clones, abstract/translate them into such aspects.  I know of no tools off-the-shelf that do this directly, so you'll need a custom tool that has all the necessary machinery.  Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com) is designed with building exactly such custom tools in mind. 
(This satisfies the "could" part of my remark; there's additional work to do to get what you want).  And in fact DMS has been used to build aspect tools for languages that don't presently have them; see [A technique for constructing aspect weavers using a program transformation engine](http://www.gray-area.org/Pubs/aosd-2004.pdf).  [It might not be a surprise to you that CloneDR is actually built on top of DMS, and an even nicer engineering path would be run the CloneDR machinery and pass the results directly to custom AOP extraction code rather than going through an intermediate export/import of clone data locations).

You also wanted open source (whenever I see this, I read this as code words for "free").  Alas, these tools are not free.  They have required decades of PhD level engineering to build and polish (some of those decades being my personal decades; I'm the architect of DMS) and I have some trouble with idea of doing that for free.   They do have commercial licenses, and can be obtained at what we think are moderate prices for the value supplied (frankly IMHO a significant part of the value is the perspective that allowed these tools to built in a general way), and there are research licenses. Contact us offline for more details; see my bio.

Comment: Dr. Baxter, thanks alot for details. i will contact you shortly.